# R: Assign value inside apply function

Tags: r, apply

I am trying to do missing imputation by apply functions. Currently I am using the following way:

```
 data <- sapply(data,function(x) 
         replace(x,list=is.na(x) & class(x) == "numeric", values=mean(x,na.rm=T)))
```

But this is not very convenient because I need to create a return value to make it work. Is there any way can assign value inside an apply function?

Ideal way would be like:

```
 sapply(data,function(x) if(class(x) == "numeric") x[is.na(x)] <- =mean(x,na.rm=T)))
```

Comment: You need to `return(x)`, something akin to `apply( df , 1 , function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <- mean(x,na.rm=TRUE); return(x) }) `

Comment: Imputing the values of missing items as the mean of the column is statistical malpractice.

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for the reply. That is what I don't want to do. Is there any way to assign value in a apply function instead of pass out to a return value.

Comment: @Yoki can you please clarify your question? What return value are you trying to avoid creating, the result of `sapply` or the result of the imputation function?
Simon's approach works for me (although I used `sapply`)...

Comment: Got it! I just tried Simon's way and works for me. Thank you guys!

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon +1 Arrived here looking for the answer you gave and it worked like a charm. My question was "How to add a value to a df based on the columns and indices returned by apply?" Adding this comment here for anyone else who may end up here.